# Norms That Define An Open Set

Tags: metric-spaces

How can a norm define a set in a vector space. I don't understand for example how 2 different norms can define a same open set.

It's not intuitive to me.

An open set doesn't need a norm to be open (or to even exist)

Comment: How do you define an open set?

Comment: It's true that an open set doesn't _need_ a norm. However, if you have a normed space $(X, \|\cdot \|)$, then the norm will in a natural way distinguish certain subsets $U\subseteq X$ that have the properties we expect open sets to have. Therefore we call those distinguished sets "the open sets of $X$ induced by the norm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about open balls or open sets?  If $|| \cdot ||$ is a norm on a vector space $V$, then an open ball in $V$ (with respect to the norm $|| \cdot ||$) is a set of the form $$ \{ v \in V : ||v - v_0|| < r \}$$ for a fixed $v_0 \in V, 0 < r \in \mathbb{R}$.  An *open set* (with respect to $|| \cdot ||$) is a set which is equal to a union of open balls in the sense of $|| \cdot ||$.

If $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, then $V$ can be identified with a finite product of $\mathbb{R}$s, which gives $V$ a topology of open sets (product topology).   As you say, these open sets are defined independently of any norm.

But it is a standard result any two norms $|| \cdot ||_1, ||\cdot ||_2$ on such a space $V$ are *equivalent*, in the sense that any open set in the sense of $|| \cdot ||_1$ is also an open set in the sense of $|| \cdot ||_2$, and vice versa.  In fact, the open sets from either of these norms are the exactly the same as the open sets of $V$ from the product topology.

This is not saying that open balls in the sense of one norm are also opens ball in the sense of the other.  Rather, any set $S \subseteq V$ which is equal to a union of various open balls in the sense of $|| \cdot ||_1$, can also be expressed as a union of other various open balls in the sense of $|| \cdot ||_2$, and vice versa.

Comment: could you provide a reference to the proof of the fact "any open set in the sense of $||\cdot||_{1}$" is also an open set in the sense of $||\cdot||_{2}$ and vice versa?

Comment: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $X$, there is the induced metric $(x,y)\mapsto \|x-y\|$, which defines a topology with the collection of all sets of the form $$ \{y\in X : \|x-y\| < r\},$$ (with $r>0$) as a basis. A subset of $X$ is open with respect to this norm off it can be written as a union of basis elements.

If two norms generate the same topology, then the open sets will be the same regardless of which norm we are using.

Answer (score 0):

With a norm you have a metric and thus a notion of distance. From this you can create balls. B(x,r) is the set of all vectors distance less than r from x. B(x,r)=B(x,s) with (WLOG) r